# In android, How to send an email without user interaction, from other than gmailsender?

Tags: android

i am using the code snippet like below

```
class SendEmailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Boolean> {
        Mail m = new Mail("someone@gmail.com", "password"); 


        public SendEmailAsyncTask() {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.v(SendEmailAsyncTask.class.getName(), "SendEmailAsyncTask()");
            String[] toArr = {"someone@domain.com"};
            m.setTo(toArr);
            m.setFrom("someone@domain.com");
            m.setSubject("Email from Android");
            m.setBody("Got message");
        }
```

I want to use someone@anydomain.com instead of someone@gmail.com.

Also is there any way to avoid using the password there?

Comment: Sending mail in background without user interaction may raise security issue for your app user. Make sure your user knows it.

Comment: I need to send that mail without knowing the user, but i need to send that mail other than from gmail domain. how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK makes it very easy to send emails from an application, but unfortunately, that's only if you want to send them via the built-in mailing app. For most situations this works fine, but if you want to send something out and don't want any input/intervention from the user, it's not as easy.

In this article I'm going to show you how to send an email in the background without the user even knowing - the application will do everything behind the scenes.

Before we begin, you'll need to download a few files via the link below - this is a special version of the JavaMail API, which was written specifically for Android.

http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list

I'll be walking you through a Mail wrapper that I wrote, which makes it much easier to send emails and even add attachments if that's something you'd like to do.

Here is the full wrapper class below, which I'll go through step by step - keeping in mind that you'll have to add the fore-said files if you want this to work. Add them as external libraries - they need to be accessible by the Mail class.

```
    import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.activation.CommandMap; 
import javax.activation.DataHandler; 
import javax.activation.DataSource; 
import javax.activation.FileDataSource; 
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap; 
import javax.mail.BodyPart; 
import javax.mail.Multipart; 
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.Transport; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart; 


public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 

  private String[] _to; 
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 

  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public Mail() { 
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

    _user = ""; // username 
    _pass = ""; // password 
    _from = ""; // email sent from 
    _subject = ""; // email subject 
    _body = ""; // email body 

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 

  public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  } 

  // more of the getters and setters ….. 
}
```

And now I'm going to go through each bit of code

```
public Mail() { 
  _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
  _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
  _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

  _user = ""; // username 
  _pass = ""; // password 
  _from = ""; // email sent from 
  _subject = ""; // email subject 
  _body = ""; // email body 

  _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
  _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

  _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

  // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
  MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
  mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
  mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
  mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
  mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
  mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
  CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
} 

public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
  this(); 

  _user = user; 
  _pass = pass; 
}
```

In this piece of code we initialise the properties, and setup the default values.

Also, we're setting up the mime types for javamail. I've also added a comment which describes why we need this.

And you've probably noticed that there are 2 constructors - one overrides the other, just incase the you want to pass the username and password when instantiating the class.

```
public boolean send() throws Exception { 
  Properties props = _setProperties(); 

  if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

    InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
      addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
    } 
    msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

    msg.setSubject(_subject); 
    msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

    // setup message body 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

    // Put parts in message 
    msg.setContent(_multipart); 

    // send email 
    Transport.send(msg); 

    return true; 
  } else { 
    return false; 
  } 
}
```

This is the most important method - here we're putting all the data from the properties and sending the mail.

```
public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
  BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
  DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
  messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
  messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

  _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
}
```

You can call this method at any time if you want to add an attachment, but make sure you call it before the send method.

```
private Properties _setProperties() { 
  Properties props = new Properties(); 

  props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

  if(_debuggable) { 
    props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
  } 

  if(_auth) { 
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
  } 

  props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

  return props; 
}
```

Here we're setting up the properties for the mail retrieval - defaulting to SMTP authentication.

Also keep in mind that this is all defaulted to connect to the Gmail (Google) SMTP server.

Below is an example of how to use the Mail wrapper, in an Android activity.

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
  super.onCreate(icicle); 
  setContentView(R.layout.main); 

  Button addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_email); 
  addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View view) { 
      Mail m = new Mail("gmailusername@gmail.com", "password"); 

      String[] toArr = {"bla@bla.com", "lala@lala.com"}; 
      m.setTo(toArr); 
      m.setFrom("wooo@wooo.com"); 
      m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
      m.setBody("Email body."); 

      try { 
        m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

        if(m.send()) { 
          Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } else { 
          Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } 
      } catch(Exception e) { 
        //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
      } 
    } 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, but i want to know that can i change that default gmail smtp server from android? is it only possible to send this mail from gmail?

Comment: try it by changing smtp configuration of your required mail configuration

Answer (score 0):

This is the Android Snippet you will have to write in the function that will trigger the mail.

The Class that will run in Async

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String> {

private Exception exception;

protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        // Creating HTTP client
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Creating HTTP Post
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                "<url>/api.php");

        // Building post parameters
        // key and value pair
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("x", "1"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", "<email id>"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("long", "Hi"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", "hi"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("header", "Hi"));

        // Url Encoding the POST parameters
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // writing error to Log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Making HTTP Request
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            // writing response to log
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
            return response.toString();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.exception = e;
        return null;
    }
    return null;

}

protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
    // TODO: check this.exception 
    // TODO: do something with the feed
}
}
```

Now you can call this way

```
new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(
            "<url>/api.php");
```

in api.php you can extract all the parameters you have sent through POST request and then send normal php mail.

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
echo "Sent";

?>
```

This much should do it.